# SQL Server 2008 Column to Row Data

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a budget table in my SQL Server database that looks something like the following:

```
create table #cols (
   acctid int, 
   yr int, 
   pd01 numeric(15,2), 
   pd02 numeric(15,2), 
   pd03 numeric(15,2), 
          .
          .
          .
   pd13 numeric(15,2),
   primary key(acctid, yr));
```

I need to take the data in the various columns and switch it to a row based format table like the following:

```
create table #rows (
  acctid int, 
  yr int, 
  pd int, 
  amt numeric(15,2), 
  primary key(acctid, yr, pd));
```

Now I could run 13 SQL statements like this:

```
insert into #rows select acctid, yr, 1, pd01 from #cols;
    .
    .
    .
insert into #rows select acctid, yr, 13, pd13 from #cols;
```

But I was wondering if there is a more efficient/elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is **UNPIVOT**

```
select acctid,yr,CAST(RIGHT(pd,2) AS INT) as pd, amt
from #cols
UNPIVOT
(amt FOR pd IN ([pd01],[pd02],[pd03],..., [pd13])) unp
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  I knew there had to be an elegant way to do this.  I've never even heard of UNPIVOT let alone used it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **union all**

```
insert into #rows
select acctid, yr, 1, pd01 from #cols;
union all
select acctid, yr, 2, pd02 from #cols;
union all
.....
union all
select acctid, yr, 13, pd13 from #cols;
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same as 13 separate statements.  Granted, it would certainly work but it's not really that much more elegant.